# List ordered in a particular way

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

```
public class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category(){CategoryType = "BP"},
            new Category(){ CategoryType ="BY"},
            new Category(){ CategoryType ="BT1"},
            new Category(){ CategoryType ="BT3"},
            new Category(){ CategoryType ="BTU"},
            new Category(){ CategoryType ="BT2"},
        };
        categoryList = categoryList.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryType).ToList();
        categoryList.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.CategoryType));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryType { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Through above program I am getting result like P

```
BT1
BT2
BT3
BTU
BY
```

However I want to have the result as `BP, BY, BT1, BT2, BT3,BTU`.

Comment: Why should `BY` come before `BT1` though, you need to explain your ordering strategy

Comment: In particular  can´t see why `P` and `Y` come before any number, but `U` after them.

Comment: It is just the order in which these categories has to be displayed

Comment: Yes, but **why** that order? You must explain the ordering. It's obviously not plain alphanumeric sorting, so what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by the category's name's length, and then by its value:

```
categoryList =
    categoryList.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryType.Length).ThenBy(x => x.CategoryType).ToList();
```